# Python with flet, how can i put Google ads

Tags: python, ads, google-ads-api, adsense, flet

I am creating an app in python with flet, and I wanted to ask if there is a way to insert in the latter the Google ads or another type of advertising

I’ve already read something online but I haven’t found anything useful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this but maybe you can insert your ads with ft.Container and in content you can insert image with url of ads.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).